# explicit group and having clause with `groupdate` gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am using `groupdate` gem for grouping the records with date/time. I want to group the records and select the users with having clause and then group the records with date/month/time. But its not giving proper result which i want.
eg:

```
User.group_by_month(:created_at).count # gives proper result but
User.joins("LEFT JOIN devices ON devices.user_id=users.id").group("users.id").having("COUNT(devices.id)=0").count #gives all users in hash while i want only count for the months.
```

I am using this for showing charts using `chartkick` gem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try `User.joins("LEFT JOIN devices ON devices.user_id=users.id").group("users.id").having("COUNT(devices.id)=0").count.length`

Comment: I cant as i just have to forward this result to the chartckick, and the code i have written is generic for all.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got workaround for it using 2 queries.

```
user_ids = User.joins("LEFT JOIN devices ON users.id=devices.user_id").group("users.id").having("count(devices.id)=0").pluck("users.id")

User.where(id: user_ids).group_by_month("created_at").count
```

Another way was to include the first query in sub-query.

```
User.where("id IN (SELECT u.id FROM users u LEFT JOIN devices ON u.id=devices.user_id GROUP BY us.id HAVING count(devices.id)=0)").group_by_month("created_at").count
```